# what's wrong with format moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, toisostring

we have 2 isoString dates:

```
startedAt: '2023-10-18T14:03:36.150Z',
closedAt: '2023-10-18T18:13:33.150Z'
```

When I'm taking duration differences it's working good:

```
const duration = moment.duration(moment(closedAt).diff(startedAt));
const days = duration.days(); // 0
const hours = duration.hours(); // 4
const minutes = duration.minutes(); // 9
const seconds = duration.seconds(); // 57
```

But, when I'm formating it shows:

```
const start = moment(startedAt).format('DD, dddd, hh:mm:ss');
const end = moment(closedAt).format('DD, dddd, hh:mm:ss');
// start: 18, wednesday, 08:03:36 (+6GMT)
// end: 19, thursday, 12:13:33 (+6GMT)
```

why, day is 19?

Comment: Your time strings are UTC (Note the Z in the end) but you are in a timezones that is 6 hours ahead of UTC. Thus 18:13 UTC is 0:13 (or 12:13 AM) in your local time And per default moment formats the time in local time

Comment: okay, if so why '2023-10-18T18:13:33.150Z' is not becoming 19, thursday, 00:13:33?

Comment: @DaniyarChangylov - Because you're using `hh`, the 12-hour "hours" formatting sequence. If you want 24-hour time, use `HH`.

Comment: It is, but as you used `hh` in the format string this is a 12 hour clock, which means 00:13 is 12;13 AM

Comment: Just to throw it out there, [moment is outdated](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and they don't recommend using it in new projects. Look at [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) or [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/), or use native methods [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Or look at Luxon which supports duration as we found out in the weekend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why, day is 19?

Because the 18th at 18:13:33 UTC is the 19th at 00:13:33 in your local timezone (GMT+06:00) (which is displayed as 12:13:33 because the `hh` format specifier is for the 12-hour clock). Those strings represent moments in time UTC (the `Z` at the end indicates that), so that's how Moment parses them. But by default, Moment formats in **local** time. So you're seeing a difference based on your timezone. You can use the [`utc`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) method to tell Moment to format using UTC instead:

```
moment(closedAt).utc().format('DD, dddd, hh:mm:ss');
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
```

Beware that `hh` is the 12-hour clock, though. Use `HH` if you want the 24-hour clock.